# Is there a way to link other NetLogo models to a NetLogo model?

Tags: netlogo, ls

I tried using the example shown in the NetLogo manual( https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/ls.html#keeping-track-of-models ).

```html
extensions [ls]

to setup
  ls:reset
  ca
  ls:create-models 30 "Wolf Sheep Predation.nlogo"
  ls:ask ls:models [ set grass? true setup ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
    ls:ask ls:models [ go ]
    show mean [ count sheep ] ls:of ls:models
end
```

Following is the message that I got from NetLogo:

```
*NetLogo is unable to supply you with more details about this error.  Please report the problem 
 at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues, or to bugs@ccl.northwestern.edu, and paste the 
contents of this window into your report. 

java.lang.Exception: Unable to open model with current format: /C:/Program Files/NetLogo 6.1.1/app/models/Sample Models/Computer Science/Wolf Sheep Predation.nlogo
 at org.nlogo.api.ModelLoader.readModel(ModelLoader.scala:65)   
 at org.nlogo.api.ModelLoader.readModel$(ModelLoader.scala:60)
 at org.nlogo.api.ConfigurableModelLoader.readModel(ModelLoader.scala:106)
 at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.open(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:502)
 at org.nlogo.ls.HeadlessChildModel.<init>(HeadlessChildModel.scala:40)
 at org.nlogo.ls.LevelSpace.createHeadlessModel(LevelSpace.scala:107)
 at org.nlogo.ls.LevelSpace.$anonfun$load$1(LevelSpace.scala:53)
 at org.nlogo.ls.CreateModels.$anonfun$perform$5(Prims.scala:189)
 at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:158)
 at org.nlogo.ls.CreateModels.perform(Prims.scala:188)
 at org.nlogo.prim._extern.perform(_extern.java:36)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.stepConcurrent(Context.java:107)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.ConcurrentJob.step(ConcurrentJob.scala:65)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.runPrimaryJobs(JobThread.scala:133)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.$anonfun$run$1(JobThread.scala:68)
 at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
 at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
 at org.nlogo.api.Exceptions$.handling(Exceptions.scala:41)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:66)
NetLogo 6.1.1
main: org.nlogo.app.AppFrame
thread: AWT-EventQueue-0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_202 (Oracle Corporation; 1.8.0_202-b08)
operating system: Windows 10 10.0 (amd64 processor)
Scala version 2.12.8
JOGL: (3D View not initialized)
OpenGL Graphics: (3D View not initialized)
model: Untitled
02:24:48.611 TickStateChangeEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$4 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) JobThread
02:24:48.611 OutputEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$4 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
02:24:48.611 AddJobEvent (org.nlogo.app.common.CommandLine) AWT-EventQueue-0
02:24:48.611 OutputEvent (org.nlogo.app.common.CommandLine) AWT-EventQueue-0
02:24:48.611 CompiledEvent (org.nlogo.window.CompilerManager) AWT-EventQueue-0
02:24:48.589 CompileMoreSourceEvent (org.nlogo.app.common.CommandLine) AWT-EventQueue-0
02:24:48.589 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$4 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
02:24:48.389 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$4 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
02:24:48.185 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$4 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
02:24:47.981 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$4 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0*
```

**Is there anyway around it?**
Please let me know if there is anything else I should include in the question.
Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible this is a path error? Is that provided path the installation path for NetLogo on your computer?

Comment: "Computer Science/Wolf Sheep Predation.nlogo" — that model isn't in that folder

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I guess I need to save both the models in the same directory. I thought given NetLogo already has the model saved into it, this won't be a problem.